# Make a background image fill all the space when rotated

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have a `div` which has been rotated 45 degrees, this creates a diamond shape. Inside I have another `div` with a minus 45-degree rotation so the content is square I set the inner container to have `100% width & height`but because of the rotation, it doesn't fill all the space.

I know the output I get is accurate to the code I've written because of the rotation it is 100%, so I suppose I need it larger than 100% and to scale as the browser scales.

```css
.headerImg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rotateBack {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerImg">
  <div class="rotateBack" style="background-image: url('https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/05-dog-breed-Safety-Tips-to-Keep-Your-Dog-in-Top-Shape-This-Summer-508549561-Yevgen-Romanenko.jpg')">

  </div>
</div>
```

An example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c4n27t7/)

Answer (score 0):

Since the container div has fixed size you can use absolute position with the image and make it overflow by specifing negative values on top/left/bottom/right;

```css
.headerImg {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
}

.rotateBack {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: -30%;
  right: -30%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerImg">
  <div class="rotateBack" style="background-image: url('https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/05-dog-breed-Safety-Tips-to-Keep-Your-Dog-in-Top-Shape-This-Summer-508549561-Yevgen-Romanenko.jpg')">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

By the way here is another way to achive what you want using clip-path:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.rotateBack {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 50%, 50% 100%, 100% 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotateBack" style="background-image: url('https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/05-dog-breed-Safety-Tips-to-Keep-Your-Dog-in-Top-Shape-This-Summer-508549561-Yevgen-Romanenko.jpg')">

</div>
```

Or using linear-gradient (but the background cannot be transparent):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.back {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background:
  linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 20%, transparent 75%, #fff 70%), 
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 20%, transparent 75%, #fff 20%), 
  url('https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/05-dog-breed-Safety-Tips-to-Keep-Your-Dog-in-Top-Shape-This-Summer-508549561-Yevgen-Romanenko.jpg') center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="part">
<div class="losange">
  <div class="los1">
    <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2178/3531465579_8bff044e9b_z.jpg?zz=1" alt="" width="255" height="320" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.losange, .losange div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.losange {
 transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(10px);
 }
 .losange .los1 {
  width: 355px;
  height: 355px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-74px);
  }
  .losange .los1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

I found this and have used for a project of mine. Hope it helps you, understand the main idea.